# Can't see products in categories after categorizing programmatically

Tags: category, indexing

Using CE 1.8.1, I've just categorized a number of products using code like this:

```
$product = mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
$product->setCategoryIds($cats);
$product->save();
```

I can't get the products to show up in their new categories on the front end. I see the results in the `catalog_category_product table` - the information is in the database.  I also see it when I edit individual products in the admin.  From the admin, I've reindexed everything and flushed all cache storage.

What can I do to see these new product categorizations?

Comment: Did you try this with products that are already showing up? So, add a product to a new category or are these new products altogether?

Comment: Did you try to add `$product->setStoreId(0)` before to save ?

Comment: did you reindex Category Products index?

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing this is to add the product to a category rather than assigning categories to a product.

Here is how Magento add a product to a category. Hope it helps...

```
public function assignProduct($categoryId, $productId, $position = null, $identifierType = null)
{
    $category = $this->_initCategory($categoryId);
    $positions = $category->getProductsPosition();
    $productId = $this->_getProductId($productId);
    $positions[$productId] = $position;
    $category->setPostedProducts($positions);

    try {
        $category->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: setCategoryIds() is a valid method, and does set the associations.  http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.html#setCategoryIds

Comment: `setCategoryIds(array)` simply set the `category_ids` data of the product. Category ids in database is edited when a product is assigned to a category.